# Deploying tracked Activity field through VS Code

Tags: vs-code, history-tracking, field-history, activityhistory

I'm having some issues figuring out how to deploy field tracking for an Activity field. I'm sure it's something to do with the weird Activity/Task/Event web that Salesforce has weaved.

I tried adding the `<trackHistory>true</trackHistory>` flag on the field that I would normally add for other objects.

When deploying I received the error ***The entity: Activity does not have history tracking enabled*** on our custom field.

I then tried adding the `<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>` tag on the Activity object. I tried this on just Activity, on just Task/Event and on all three. If I include this on the Activity object I get the deployment error: ***Entity does not support history tracking*** on the Activity object.

I know the ability to track Activity fields is semi new - available in the Spring '23 release. Is this just not available to deploy through VS Code or what am I doing wrong?